# How do I use google's reCaptcha V3 service in my selenium script?

Tags: python, django, selenium, recaptcha

I was given a method to solve captchas on a website. The thing is, now that I wrote the scraping script, I don't know how I'm supposed to use this method for it to solve me the captcha in my target website (I'm using selenium).
I located the element but that's about it.

So where do I use the method if it's like this?:

```
resolve_simple_captcha(image_base64)
```

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import Mon
from app.ws_sr_padron import get_persona
from app.captcha import resolve_simple_captcha
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class ConstanciaInscripcion(FormView):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
    
    def post(self,request):

        form = Mon(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['Email']

        cuit_r = int(request.POST["CUIT"])
        response = get_persona(cuit_r)
        
        try:
            nombre = response["persona"]["nombre"]
            apellido = response["persona"]["apellido"]
        except KeyError:
            nombre, apellido = None, None
            print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")

        except TypeError:
            nombre, apellido = None, None
            print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")
        
        else:
            print(nombre, apellido)
        
            if form.is_valid():
                cuit = form.cleaned_data.get('CUIT')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('Email')
                cuit.save()
                email.save()
                return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')            

        #Selenium script
        DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/chromedriver.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
        driver.get('https://google.com') #I changed the url for this

        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) 
        elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='cuit']")))
        elem.send_keys(cuit_r)
        
        elem2= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='CaptchaCode']")))
      
        resolve_simple_captcha(elem2)
        elem4 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="btnConsultar"]')))
        elem4.click()
      
        return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

Comment: if you want to captcha before you display anything to user navigating to `app/constancia-inscripcion.html`, then I would put it as the first thing in your `get` method.  If you want to display it when they `post` (maybe a button with a form submission?) somewhere in `post`.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, make a decorator (say, `@captcha` and decorate those methods.  That decorator might read cookies off the client's computer.  Then you would captcha -> success -> place cookie, then you wouldn't have to captcha again till cookie expiry.  There might already be decorators out there that do this.  You can then reuse that one decorator on all your endpoints.

Comment: When does captcha happen?  Are you trying to solve it automatically yet not know when it happens?  If so, you would need some way to capture the captcha window and interact with that.

Comment: @RazzleShazl The thing is, the captcha happens in the driver.get website. So basically the user inputs the id and I have to solve the captcha with the method Through selenium. The captcha is not on the website I'm writing but on the one I'm "getting". The captcha is under the "cuit" the person inputs in the other website (through selenium). What I need is to pass the captcha so I can get to the file I need in the other website.

Comment: I'm sorry, i deleted that because that wasn't supposed to be there. That is for the captcha in my website so I took it out since that's not what I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: Can you repurpose that code then?  Sounds like  you already have it working for one website?

Comment: The code doesn't work when it comes to solving the captcha through selenium for the other party's website. That piece of code that was there before was just a captcha for my website.

Comment: I think the only thing you need to solve is obtaining from your `elem2` the `base64` image which you can pass to your function.  Is it in there?  If you can debug, put a break after `elem2` is assigned, then inspect everything inside it.

Comment: How do I get the base64? I got the xpath of the place where the image is but it doesn't work. The website is this: https://seti.afip.gob.ar/padron-puc-constancia-internet/ConsultaConstanciaAction.do and the captcha is there but I'm not sure how to get it.